# Print significant auto-correlation value

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, correlation

If I do an autocorrelation test in R (`acf`), I get a great graph, and the horizontal lines show the cutoff of significance.

`acf` also prints out the individual lag values in the console, however, here I can't see which are significant. Is there an easy way to do that without looking at the graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So basically for this we need to know the cutoff value. By writing `acf` and `stats:::plot.acf` you can see that it might be different for different parameter values, but for default values here is what you should use:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- arima.sim(list(ar = 0.5), 100)
r <- acf(x, plot = FALSE)$acf
which(abs(r)[-1] >= qnorm(1 - 0.05 / 2) / sqrt(length(x)))
# [1]  1  2  3  9 10 12 13
```

where 0.05 is the significance level in this case.

Comment: Great. It also works for ccf (as long as I leave $acf). Do you know if I could show which number of lag it is?

Comment: @dorien, `idx <- 1:length(r) - (length(r) + 1) / 2; idx[abs(r) >= qnorm(1 - 0.05 / 2) / sqrt(length(x))]`

Comment: sorry, what is that last statement about exactly?

Comment: @dorien, `idx <- 1:length(r) - (length(r) + 1) / 2` gives a vector of lags for the ccf case, e.g. -10, -9, ..., 9, 10, and then `abs(r) >= qnorm(1 - 0.05 / 2) / sqrt(length(x))` gives a logical vector with `TRUE` at those positions where a corresponding lag is significant. Using this logical vector you can subset `idx` to get the result.